# SQL LIKE Statement in VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sql-like

I am trying to convert this Access SQL statement into a usable VB.net statement but I am not sure how to correctly format this.

```
  SELECT Portfolio.[Team/Asset] FROM Portfolio WHERE (((Portfolio.[Team/Asset]) Like "BE*")) OR (((Portfolio.[Team/Asset]) Like "*BE*"))
```

Comment: The SQL is still valid if you use Access as the database. If you use another database than Access, you may have to adjust to the SQL dialect of that database.

Comment: Well in Visual Studio I am getting the End of Statement Expected error, so my guess that there is an issue with the statement on that end.  I am just trying to figure out how to format it correctly to pass to Access.

Comment: Hard to tell without your code.

Comment: I just figured it out.  Looks like VB.net doesn't like the *.  So I had to code the Where clause this way: WHERE [Team/Asset] Like '%BE%'"